# Replace deprecated Java Date to Calendar.set ou GregorianCalendar.set in a static context

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I'm working on Android project using Java and Android Studio IDE is warning me Date(int, int, int) is deprecated as of API16, but when I replace it to Calendar.set the build fails as non-static method cannot be referenced in a static context.

This method is being called on a date picker onItenSelectedListener that is static

How it can be deprecated if there is no replacement that can be really used?

Comment: Please add your code for further investigation

Comment: You cannot call a non-static function from a static context.Kindly add the warning message from IDE too.

Comment: The last one date manipulation api that includes LocalDate and LocalDateTime comes with several resources. https://www.journaldev.com/2800/java-8-date-localdate-localdatetime-instant

Comment: Using `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, is an excellent idea. On the ohter hand an answer not containing much more than a link isn’t really considered helpful on Stack Overflow. Could you please edit your answer and summarize the important point(s) from your link and/or explain how it answers the question? That would be wonderful.

Comment: java.time is an alternative for replace deprecated date api. To explain how all this  works a link with tutorial makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

Use `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It’s much nicer to work with.

```
    int year = 2019;
    int month = 10;
    int day = 15;

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
    System.out.println(date);
```

The output from this snippet is:

> 2019-10-15

`LocalDate` numbers both years and months the same way humans do, so there’s no subtracting funny values to adjust. If you need a `Date` for an API not yet upgraded to java.time, the conversion goes like this:

```
    Instant startOfDay = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
    Date oldfashionedDate = DateTimeUtils.toDate(startOfDay);
    System.out.println(oldfashionedDate);
```

> Tue Oct 15 00:00:00 CEST 2019

The classes `Date`, `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar` are all poorly designed and all long outdated. So do consider not using them.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in. Only in this case for converting from `Instant` to `Date` use `Date.from(startOfDay)`.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem replacing

```
return new Date(year-1900, month, day)
```

by

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
calendar.set(year, month-1, day);
return calendar.getTime();
```

Comment: It doesn’t give the same result, though. Using the example values from my answer I got `Fri Nov 15 00:00:00 CET 2019` from your first snippet and `Tue Oct 15 20:11:33 CEST 2019` from the other one. I’d  say the similarity is non-trivial to spot. This is how confusing the old date and time classes are.